# Why am I unable to create a Nokogiri node?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I’m using Rails 4.2.7 with Nokogiri.  How do I create a new Nokogiri node to add to my document?  I thought I could do this

```
general = doc.xpath("//lomimscc:general")
title = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new "lomimscc:title"
string = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new "lomimscc:string"
string.content = scenario.title
string.language = 'en' 
title << string 
general << title
```

but I’m getting the error

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2+)
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/sims/app/helpers/myproject_helper.rb:73:in `new'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/sims/app/helpers/myproject_helper.rb:73:in `set_manifest_title'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/sims/app/helpers/myproject_helper.rb:59:in `generate_manifest_file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Nokogiri::XML::Node.new` expects 2 arguments.  From the [rdoc](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node):

```
.new(name, document) ⇒ Object
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier than you're making it:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
EOT
```

At this point there's a parsed document and looking at the body shows it's empty:

```
doc.at('body').to_html # => "<body>\n  </body>"
```

Nokogiri is smart enough to know what to do if you pass it a node as a string:

```
doc.at('body').inner_html = '<p>foo</p>'
doc.at('body').to_html # => "<body><p>foo</p></body>"
```

It parsed the string, then added it as the inner HTML of the body.

It can also append nodes based on some other node:

```
doc.at('p').add_next_sibling('<p>bar</p>')
doc.at('body').to_html # => "<body>\n<p>foo</p>\n<p>bar</p>\n</body>"
```

When you read the documentation pay close attention to the parameters, because you'll see `node_or_tags` which means it takes a Nokogiri::XML::Node or a string which describes the content to insert.

This also means it's really easy to use string interpolation to control what's being inserted:

```
t = 'foobar'
doc.at('body').inner_html = "<p>#{t}</p>"
doc.at('body').to_html # => "<body><p>foobar</p></body>"
```